# MySQL DB is ignoring foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I've got a really strange (and scary) issue: My mySQL DB is generally ignoring foreign key constraints!

All my tables are `InnoDB` and I'm creating them with liquibase like this:

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_account_id"
    baseTableName="account_transaction"
    constraintName="fk_account_transaction_user_account_id"
    referencedColumnNames="id"
    referencedTableName="user_account"/>
```

The foreign keys are created fine. In HeidiSQL I see them like this:
[image: heidiSQL DB Management]

I also checked for `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` and I've set it to 1 (`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`)

All my ID columns have the data type `BIGINT` (dunno if that matters).

What is also worth to mention: The following statement

```
  SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```

returns a bunch of constraints, but no foreign key constraints... When I execute the same statement on my local mySQL DB, it returns all the constraints INCLUDING foreign key constraints. I can't figure out what's the difference between them though...

Any help is very much appreciated :)

@Update:
So the hint with MyISAM and InnoDB did the trick. I did investigate that before. However, for some reason my tables are InnoDB, but my DB is MyISAM. I'm gonna make further investigations on that :)
[image]

Comment: Are the tables using the MyISAM storage engine? You must use InnoDB. Foreign key constraints are ignored in other storage engines. `SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();`

Comment: Unfortunately they’re all InnoDB, as I mentioned above

Comment: If the FOREIGN KEY constraints aren't showing in information_schema.table_constraints, they aren't defined. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE account_transaction` to confirm. (Most likely explanation is the storage engine isn't InnoDB - check that as Bill Karwin suggested, the ENGINE column of information_schema.tables. I think HeidiSQL is showing the indexes, not the constraints. Sounds as if Liquibase is getting in the way more than it is helping.)

Comment: Another possibility is that Liquibase alteration has not yet been run against this schema.

Comment: Hi.  Please read & act on [mcve]. PS Turns out it helps in debugging to not frame the situation as "mySQL DB is generally ignoring foreign key constraints!" but instead as "almost certainly I have made another error in reasoning and/or interpretation". Eg the situation is not  "strange", it happens all the time; that's why SO exists. I'll take "scary" as poetic; but it still isn't iikely to be saying anything about anything but your approach to programming.

Comment: First hit googling 'liquibase no foreign keys mysql': "When I add ENGINE=INNODB to the Liquibase version, it does create the foreign keys." & "You can also set your default table type to innodb in the my.cnf file".

Comment: Guys please calm down... I did Google the issue. The thing is that my tables are InnoDB, but for some reason my DB is MyISAM (see screenshot in my updated post). I'm gonna analyse that. I'll also take a look at the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, thanks.

Comment: I doublechecked my storage settings, and all tables are definitely set to INNODB. I will also add ´SHOW CREATE TABLE account_transaction´ query (as @spencer7593 suggested) and it shows that there are keys defined. Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: I don't really think this is an issue with foreign keys in MySQL. I think the issue is the DDL generated by **Liquibase**.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because on my local db all foreign keys work as expected, and I also added them with liquibase there. The only difference I can think of is that on my remote db I changed the storage engine to innodb afterwards

Comment: What was the storage engine the foreign key constraint was added? e.g. `ALTER TABLE foo_c ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foo_c_foo_p FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES foo_p (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`.  If it was MyISAM when that was executed, I think we've come full circle, back to the original comment from Bill Karwin... everything shown makes it look like the tables were MyISAM when that statement was executed. And MySQL added a KEY (an index) but did not add a FOREIGN KEY constraint. Later changing the storage engine to InnoDB doesn't create foreign keys.

Comment: This behavior is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual. The behavior can be demonstrated with some simple test vases. (As I noted in an earlier comment, HeidiSQL is *not* showing foreign key constraints defined on the table. It's showing the indexes defined on the table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bill Karwin notes in his comment, FOREIGN KEY constraints are *ignored* if the table is not InnoDB.

Demonstration:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_p
( id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=MYISAM
;  

CREATE TABLE foo_c
( id   BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
, p_id BIGINT UNSIGNED
) ENGINE=MYISAM
;
```

Add a foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_c 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foo_c_foo_p
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES foo_p (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
;
```

MySQL creates an *index* but not a foreign key.

Change storage engine to InnoDB does not create foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_p ENGINE=INNODB ;

ALTER TABLE foo_c ENGINE=INNODB ;
```

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo_c` to see table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo_c` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `p_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_foo_c_foo_p` (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

There's an index (converted from the MyISAM definition) but no foreign key.

To add a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE foo_c 
  DROP KEY fk_foo_c_foo_p  
, ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foo_c_foo_p
  FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES foo_p (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
;
```

A `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows the FOREIGN KEY constraint, as well as the index that was automatically created:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo_c` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `p_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_foo_c_foo_p` (`p_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_foo_c_foo_p` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `foo_p` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Comment: Wow, that makes so much sense! Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trusting MySQL docs. According to it foreign key can be defined as part of column definition, what was not true in my case. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE badchild (id INT PRIMARY KEY, parent_id INT REFERENCES parent(id));
CREATE TABLE goodchild (id INT PRIMARY KEY, parent_id INT, FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id));
```

**goodchild** has foreign key, **badchild** has no foreign key. Statement does not fail, it is just silent ignore of instruction. It was MySQL 8.0.20 running on Windows, may be it is fixed in some later versions.